# Multiple activities within a class?

Tags: android, android-activity

So what I want to do is this. I want to have a class that contains other classes which start activities, but I'm not sure if its possible, or even a good idea. An Example:

```
public class General{
     public class Activity1 extends Activity{
          //Start Activity
     }
}
```

Is there a way to call such an activity?

Comment: Definitely possible, definitely not a good idea, definitely NOT necessary! The whole point of OOP is to avoid things like this.

Comment: What do you plan to do? The class which you extend with Activity must be "doer" of the activity

Comment: My thinking was that it would be easier to organize the activities if I group like ones in the same class

Comment: Might as well use an interfaces or abstract classes to get you some hierarchy, or packages to keep classes organized.  If you're not used to using stuff like that, its well worth the time trying it out.

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking packages would be the better way to go. Thanks for the rapid response. Is there a way to mark the question as answered or should I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I chose to go with was to use packages. After reading about it here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html and here [Android: Including multiple Java Packages to Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935443/android-including-multiple-java-packages-to-manifest) , it seems like a better method to do what I stated above.