# n-tierd architecture in eclipse for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, model-view-controller, architecture

I want to group classes together in different packages in my android project I am writing in eclipse. Similar the the MVC approach.

I was wondering how I would go about this, I tried it and I am getting errors from the manifest, how do I successfully add more than one package?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Could you post your manifest? It might help get to the bottom of the issue.

Also, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935443/android-including-multiple-java-packages-to-manifest/3935810#3935810), as it seems to be what you want.

Basically, create subpackages for each aspect. So they would be

```
com.yourapp.model
com.yourapp.view
com.yourapp.controller
```

and your manifest would look like

```
<manifest package="com.yourapp" . . . >
    <application . . .>
        <activity android:name=".model.Activity1" . . . />
        <activity android:name=".view.Activity2" . . . />
        <activity android:name=".controller.Activity3" . . . />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But you might not have activities in each of these packages, that's just to show you how you could access them if you need to.

Comment: It works now, although the database has been emptied, not important data but strange, any idea why this may have happened? also I haven't needed to specify the package name in the andrtoid:name attribute, just the class name seems fine.

Comment: You should post another question about that